# load another html file as a popup before loading the actual html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

if i have the following html file like index.html

```html
<html>
<body>

<div>
<p>Sample html</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and consider i have another html page named example.html
before loading the index.html i need to load this example.html as a popup. how is it possible

Comment: You will use js to control which form you want to show first.  Then when the user clicks ok or closes the form, show the second one.

Comment: can you please explain as an answer

Comment: Do you want it to open in the iframe of the same window or in iframe of pop up?

Comment: same window. we see some image with offers when we visit some websites right?. just like that in the same window just like an image i want to load the html file(only after closing this box,the user should view the real page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write the following code in index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    index Page
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var myWindow = window.open("example.html", "", "width=700,height=500");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And create an another html file called example.html in the same directory. Whenever open the index.html page the example.html file will open itself in a popup window

Comment: your answer is almost there. the thing is i dont want to show the page in another windows. i need to show it in the same window like an image or something(plain html without borders)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put your example.html codes inside the div tags for responsiveness and clean instead of iframe but here I used iframe for your question.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
 <iframe src='example.html' width='600' height='350'> </iframe>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Reference link : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: its not comming as a popup its just displaying above my real page

Comment: you want pop-up or not?